# C++ overloaded functions

Tags: c++, function, types, return, overloading

In C++ can you have overloaded functions with the same parameter types but different return types?

The idea of overloaded functions is this
     int foo (int x, int y);
     int foo (double x, double y);

But will this work?
     int foo (int x, int y);
     double foo (int x, int y);

if the second way works, how does the compiler know which function to choose?

Comment: No you can't. The parameter types are what C++ uses to determine which function to call.

Comment: You can't anyway. At least in C++.

Comment: The problem is that C++ is perfectly fine with you simply discarding values of function calls. What would happen if you did `foo(0,0);` as a statement by itself? Which function would get called?

Comment: The way to store it as an int vs a double after the function completes would be - to return value and probably return it with something higher hierarchically and then just demoted by setting it equal to an integer?

Comment: @Josh - that was my question. My suspicious was that you couldn't for that very reason but I wanted to confirm.